# How to Configure Virtual Hosts on Apache server on Ubuntu 15

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, configuration, virtualhost

I am setting up a few virtual hosts for my local Apache environment. I followed this as a basic guide: http://www.unixmen.com/setup-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-15-10/

At the moment, I have the following structure:
`/var/www/home` - there is a script here that looks inside the "sites" directory and produces a page with a button for each folder in the "sites" directory
`/var/www/sites` - all sites are stored here.

My home.dev points to /var/www/home and localhost points to `/var/www/sites` (so I can type localhost/site1, if needed)

The problem is that only the localhost and home.dev work properly. When I address other sites, I get "requested URL not found" error. What is even stranger, I get the same page when I type **"localhost"** or **"home.dev."** This should not be happening. To be clear, none of the other sites work. I provide phpMyAdmin site as an example. Here are the listings of some config files. Can anyone give me a clue of what's going wrong?

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/home.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.home.dev
        ServerAlias home.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/home/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/home>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/localhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
        ServerAlias localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/
        <Directory/>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/sites>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin.dev.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.dev
        ServerAlias phpmyadmin.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/phpmyadmin
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/sites/phpmyadmin>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   userman-desktop
127.0.2.1   home.dev
127.0.3.1   phpmyadmin.dev
127.0.5.1   sites.dev


::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: This question may be better suited to Server Fault

Comment: I also asked there. Hopefully, double-dipping is cool on this site.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable your virtual hosts configurations, to do this try something like

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/home.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enable/
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin.dev.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enable/
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/localhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enable/
```

then restart the apache service

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And your **/etc/hosts** should be

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   userman-desktop
127.0.0.1   home.dev
127.0.0.1   phpmyadmin.dev
127.0.0.1   sites.dev


::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and your **home.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName home.dev #<--- change this
        ServerAlias home.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/home/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/home>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, I checked the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ folder after reading your suggestion and found the following there:

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Nov 28 18:32 home.conf -> ../sites-available/home.conf

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Nov 28 21:40 phpmyadmin.conf -> ../sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   38 Nov 29 19:19 phpmyadmin.dev.conf -> ../sites-available/phpmyadmin.dev.conf

That is, it seems like the symlinks are already there.

Comment: I see. Yes, I have tried that version of /etc/hosts. I changed it in hopes of fixing it.